# Property 'fit' in type Button' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'IButton'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Fit'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a class Button, which implements IButton interface.

```
class Button implements IButton {
   public fit = 'medium';
}
```

```
declare type Fit = 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';

export interface IButton {
  fit: Fit;
}
```

I would expect to be able to assign `medium` as a default value to the `fit` property, but TypeScript throws an error when I try to do that.

```
Property 'fit' in type 'Button' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'IButton'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Fit'.
```

Is there a different way to archive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare the variable as `public fit = 'medium'`, TypeScript will infer the type of `fit` to be `string`. This does not match the interface `IButtons`'s property `fit` which is of a narrower type.

You have multiple options to fix this:

1. Declare the variable as `readonly`

```
public readonly fit = 'medium'
```

2. Use `as const` or `as Fit`

```
public fit = 'medium' as Fit
//public fit = 'medium' as const
```

3. Manually declare the correct type

```
public fit: Fit = 'medium'
```

Note: **Only `as Fit` or the 3rd option will let you modify the value of `fit` during runtime.**

Comment: I see, thank you!
Looks like I cannot avoid typing it as a Fit again(which I was trying to avoid).

Answer (score 1):

You could try to export the Enum Fit and do as below.

```
class Button implements IButton {
   public fit = 'medium' as Fit;
}
```